# HTTPS Certificate issue

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, xml-rpc, truststore

I am getting following error while using certificate file, I have generated truststore of the same and passing it to `XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory`

> org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: I/O error while communicating with HTTP server: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're dealing with is a certificate chain issue and not an XML-RPC specific issue.

You will need to look up how to get your XML-RPC client to implicitly trust the certificate and not do more than a cursory validation.

There are examples of this, I'm just not sure how to tie it to your particular XML-RPC client.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your truststore doesn't trust the certificate provided by the peer.

> I have generated truststore of the same

What exactly do you mean by that?